# ¿Se puede trabajar sql server con servidor remoto en una aplicacion dot net maui?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, maui

Tengo una aplicación de dot net maui y tengo un servidor remoto con una base de datos en una computadora externa de donde trabajo el código de dot net maui. Ya tengo conectadas las dos computadoras.

Tengo entendido que dot net maui puede trabajar con sql server de forma local pero lo que yo quiero es subir datos de la aplicación a un servidor.

Comment: No, como dice la pregunta tengo sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SÍ**, es posible conectar una aplicación .net MAUI con un motor de bases de datos remoto.

En un principio la respuesta me pareció obvia, pero luego recordé que en Blazor Wasm y en el extinto Silverlight esto no era posible, y había que crear un DAL (*data access layer*) obligatoriamente.

Así que para estar seguro tomé una pequeña aplicación de consola y la llevé a MAUI y solo tuve que realizar un pequeño cambio en el *connection string*.

Connection string original:

```
Server=XXXXX;Database=XXXXX;User Id=XXXX;Password=XXXX;
```

Connection string para .Net MAUI:

```
Server=XXXXX;Database=XXXXX;User Id=XXXX;Password=XXXX;TrustServerCertificate=True
```

Es decir, con agregar `TrustServerCertificate=True` no tuve más problema.

Por último, y solo un detalle: es el framework se llama `.net`, NO `.dot net`.

Comment: `.` en inglés se dice DOT. Así que efectivamente el nombre `.net` se pronuncia `dot net`, no es necesario poner el `dot` porque `.` ya es `dot`. En español también es correcto decir "Punto net", aunque la mayoría de la gente que trabajamos en este mundo estamos acostumbrados a utilizar los términos en inglés y mucha gente te entiende mejor si usas los términos ingleses aunque sea mal pronunciados que si usas los españoles. Por experiencia lo digo... a mi todavía me cuesta entender a qué se refieren cuando alguien me habla de cadenas!